# Execute tests using the same static object in sequential order

Tags: c#, xunit

Some of my tests uses a static class which makes it impossible to run them in full isolation.

Therefore I'm wondering if there are a way to tell xunit that some of the tests (in different test classes) in sequential order?

NCrunch has the [`[ExclusivelyUses("TheStaticClass")]`](https://www.ncrunch.net/documentation/reference_runtime-framework_exclusively-uses-attribute) attribute and I'm looking for something similar (so that the build server do not fail on them).

Comment: Not entirely sure if this will work, but the accepted answer to this question might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973556/unittesting-static-classes

Comment: @swatsonpicken Unfortunately not as the reset method can affect other tests that run simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use the xunit Collection attribute. I have used it when I had a singleton class that could not be used concurrently. Tests in the same collection do not run in parallel. See section "Custom Test Collection" here https://xunit.github.io/docs/running-tests-in-parallel.html.

```
[Collection("Our Test Collection #1")]
public class TestClass1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
}

[Collection("Our Test Collection #1")]
public class TestClass2
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

It might also be a good idea to use a custom collection fixture for custom cleanup after all the tests in the collection has been run.